# How to get single value within a subgroup in R

Tags: r, dataframe, counting

I want to sum-up all entries of observations in R but the data contains duplicates 
and I do not want to count them double; only once. Each Emittent should count only as one entry.

So far, I have tried the following syntax
`count(Subgroup_2016, vars= c("Emittent"))`

I am working in data frames in R.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear do you want to know how many different values are in "Emittent" column of "Subgroup_2016" `dataframe` ? If it's the case you just have to do `length(unique(Subgroup_2016$Emittent))` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably `n_distinct` (using `dplyr`) instead of `count`.

For example using `mtcars` built-in data set:

```
n_distinct(mtcars$cyl)
# [1] 3
```

In your case:

```
n_distinct(Subgroup_2016$Emittent)
```

Comment: `sum(!duplicated(Subgroup_2016$Emittent))`

Comment: Is there also a way to extract pairs with this formula? n_distinct(Subgroup_2016$Emittent&Investor) - I would suggest:n_distinct(DF$Emittent,DF$Investor)

Comment: `n_distinct(c(Subgroup_2016$Emittent, Subgroup_2016$Investor))`

Comment: This suggestion give a wrong answer; n_distinct(DF$Emittent,DF$Investor) seems to work out find - but I do not understand why!